# How to fix JS Calculator starting problem?

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator

**HTML tag:**

```
  <div class="display">
     <p class="display-1">0</p>
     <p class="display-2">0</p>
     <p class="temp-result">0</p>
  </div>

  <div class="telo">

    <div class="button all-clear">C</div>
    <div class="button last-entity-clear">CE</div>
    <div class="button operation">%</div>
    <div class="button operation">/</div>
    <div class="button number">7</div>
    <div class="button number">8</div>
    <div class="button number">9</div>
    <div class="button operation">X</div>
    <div class="button number">4</div>
    <div class="button number">5</div>
    <div class="button number">6</div>
    <div class="button operation">-</div>
    <div class="button number">1</div>
    <div class="button number">2</div>
    <div class="button number">3</div>
    <div class="button operation">+</div>
    <div class="button number btn-0">0</div>
    <div class="button number dot">.</div>
    <div class="button equal">=</div>

  </div>

</div>
```

**JS picture:**
[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFV1C.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFV1C.png <===

And it says that is problem on 16' line in JavaScript, that numbers.forEach is not function...

I started to learn JS but i don't know why in every easy project i need to have problems like this that a function is not function.

Comment: Please include full JS code to question instead of embeding it as a picture.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` to return a collection of elements. `querySelector` returns a single (the first) matching element

Answer (score 0):

According to the MDN documentation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

using querySelectorAll will return all elements matching what you require

```
const numbersE1=document.querySelectorAll('.number')
```

Then the proper usage should be the above